# Primal-dual schema in approximation algorithms

Tags: algorithms, approximation, linear-programming

I was studying Set Cover via the Primal–Dual Schema on my own that I faced a problem in the following paragraph:
Consider an LP-relaxation for an NP-hard problem. In general, the relaxation
will not have an optimal solution that is integral(why?? when we relax an LP we can choose the variables from the interval of [0,1] so the solution must be integral!!!). Does this rule out a complementary slackness condition driven approach? Interestingly enough, the answer is ‘no’. It turns out that the algorithm can be driven by a suitable relaxation of these conditions!(what this paragraph tries to say, I don't get the concept of relaxation here, why we do it??)
I apologize for my long question, I really appreciate if anybody can help me.

Comment: The usual rule is one question per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking many questions. I will only answer the first.

The answer to the first question is that in linear programming we cannot enforce the variables to be integers. Therefore the optimal solution could be *fractional*. Consider for example the vertex cover problem for a graph $G = (V,E)$:

$$
\begin{align*}
&\min \sum_{v \in V} x_v \\
s.t. \quad& x_u + x_v \geq 1 \text{ for all } (u,v) \in E \\
& x_v \in \{0,1\}
\end{align*}
$$

This is an integer program whose LP relaxation is

$$
\begin{align*}
&\min \sum_{v \in V} x_v \\
s.t. \quad& x_u + x_v \geq 1 \text{ for all } (u,v) \in E \\
& 0 \leq x_v \leq 1
\end{align*}
$$

Now take the case of the triangle. The smallest vertex cover has size 2, but the optimal solution for the LP is $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$. As you can see, it isn't integral.

Comment: thank u for answering one of  my questions, but my main question is about the relaxing part, I have really problem with that. even if it is a definition where this relaxation is used in primal-dual schema for set cover problem, just for proving approximation factor??

Comment: You should split your question to three different questions corresponding to the three different parts.